# Is there an aggregate function to multiply column values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to multiply column values within a table using an aggregate function in MYSQL similar to `sum(column1)` or `avg(column1)`.
I have tried `product(column1)` but the `product` function does not work.
Kindly assist.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Just by multiplying a few rows you can get really big numbers and will run into data type overflows pretty quickly. I don't know if it makes sense to multiply more than a few rows. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your values are integers greater than zero, you can do:

```
round(exp(sum(log(column1))))
```

Comment: This is what i wanted. is there any caveat if my values are in decimal and I remove `round`?

Comment: it may introduce rounding errors; you'd have to try it on your data to see how well it does

Comment: for instance, if I do it on 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, I get 40320.00000000002 not 40320

Comment: probably has to do with precision but I'm ok with 2 decimal points